# why android 4.4 ActivityManagerService create two ActivityStack, one is HomeStack, the other is FoucsStack?

Tags: android

why android 4.4 ActivityManagerService create two ActivityStack, one is HomeStack, the other is FoucsStack?   i think  one stack will be ample for the purpose， the android team why do this? i think the team may be have a problem that can't resolve it ? what's the question?

i have tried to think , but no answer.

```
/** The stack containing the launcher app. Assumed to always be attached to
 * Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY. */
ActivityStack mHomeStack;

/** The stack currently receiving input or launching the next activity. */
ActivityStack mFocusedStack;
```